# Why do photoelectrons from a vacuum photocell move towards the collector plate if it is not charged? Has it been charged beforehand?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, potential, photoelectric-effect

Why do photoelectrons from a vacuum photocell move towards the collector plate if it is not charged? Has it been charged beforehand, or do they simply move forwards because of the kinetic energy they have gained?

The kinetic energy option sounds reasonable, because then it would give a measure of the electrons' energy (which is what the photoelectric cell is used for), but then why are diagrams showing the plates already charged?

[image]

Comment: Re, "...if it is not charged." What do you think is the purpose of the "Plate Potential Battery" in that circuit?

Comment: @SolomonSlow it would create a negative potential difference, opposing the kinetic energy of the electrons and so when the current becomes 0A, the voltage would give an indication of the electrons' kinetic energy

Comment: OK, and how does that "potential difference" relate to the word you used earlier, "Charge?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow I see what you mean, but the real question should be why the CHARGED electrodes are necessary

Answer (score 2):

> the real question should be why the CHARGED electrodes are necessary

Because electrons are charged particles.

The electrons in the negatively charged cathode feel attraction to the positively charged anode, but the pull is not quite strong enough to free them unless they happen to be hit by a photon of light. Then, after they fly through the vacuum to the anode, the action of the battery restores the potential difference, accepting electrons from the tube's anode, and sending more electrons to the cathode.

The final part of the story is that resistor.  In order for electrons to get from the anode to the battery, they must first move through the resistor. Moving electrons == "current," And according to Ohm's Law, when there is current through a resistor, then there must be voltage across it.  The connection points labelled "To Vacuum Tube Amplifier" are where that voltage can be measured.

Comment: Wouldn't photoelectrons move towards the electrode anyway if it wasn't charged because of their kinetic energy? This would explain the fact that even if the charges are switched around (so the cathode becomes the anode), a small current is still detected until the voltage is high enough to overcome the photoelectrons' kinetic energy